# Connecting to Paypal Rest Api to obtain users consent

Tags: rest, paypal, coldfusion

I am trying to connect to Paypal to get a users consent to access their paypal payment history.  The end goal would be to download payments received at the end of the day and take the info and dump it into a local database.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#obtain-users-consent

```
<Cfset returnlink="http://www.xxxxxx.com/paypal/paypalreturn.cfm">

<cfset paypalLink="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize">
<Cfset paypallink="#paypallink#?client_id=#settingsLive.clientid#">
<Cfset paypallink="#paypallink#&redirect_uri=#urlencodedformat(returnlink)#">
<Cfset paypallink="#paypallink#&response_type=code">
<Cfset paypallink="#paypallink#&scope=profile+email+address+phone+https%3A%2F%2Furi.paypal.com%2Fservices%2Fpaypalattributes">
<cfset paypalLink="#paypallink#&nonce=#createUUID()#">
<cfset paypalLink="#paypallink#&state=create">


<a href="<cfoutput>#paypalLink#</cfoutput>">Login with paypal</a>
```

Clicking on the link below returns:

> Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request
>   does not match with the registered redirect_uri. Please check the
>   request.

I have logged into the Rest API, modified my app and made sure the redirect uri's for the test and live return link match that listed above.  I have also made sure that the accept logins options are checked.

I have also tried the same code against their sandbox URL:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/auth/protocol/openidconnect/v1/authorize
```

and instead of receiving the validation error, I get a page cannot be displayed.

I've tried every combination of things that I could think of
1) removing 1 cfset statement at a time to isolate a bad variable
2) making sure the return uri was a https vs http
3) switching to sandbox mode url and back

I've connected to other oauth2 api's in the past, but can't figure this one out.

Comment: If everything is set properly in your app, could you post the full URL that is output in `paypalLink`?

Comment: On my first test, I had it blank, then I went and filled in the URL.. and then I spend 30 minutes with the above code and it still didnt work.  About an hour after this ticket, I created another rest app and it worked like a charm on the first try.

Answer (score 3):

This has changed a bit, and will presumably change again soon... but here's how you do this now.

- Log into developer.paypal.com
- Click on Dashboard (https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications)
- Click your app name under "Rest API Apps"
- Scroll to the box at the bottom of the screen labeled "Sandbox (or Live) App Settings
- Set the **Return URL** (Where users will be redirected after test transactions)
- Click save

**NOTE**

This Return URL must exactly match the **redirect_uri** that you pass in via querystring (so it's confusing as to why you'd need to pass it in in the first place)

**GOTCHA**

At this point in time, the **Return URL** can seemingly never be updated. In my recent experience, if you don't type it correctly the first time you save it, you will have to create a new app.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have seen this error is when your `redirect_uri` does not match the one set in your applications profile.

You need to set this value inside of your app on the developer website.

- Log into [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com)
- Click Applications
- Under My Rest Apps click your App name
- Click Edit next to App redirect URLs
- Set the return URLs for live or test
- Save

I am also unable to get sandbox to work for my Log In with PayPal tests so it is not just you.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (October 2015), [the Dashboard](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications) Return URL should correspond to the `redirect_uri`.  You can obtain the `redirect_uri` parameter in Firefox, by downloading the HTTPFox browser plugin.  Then you start HTTPFox, point your browser to the OmniAuth login link, and view the `scParams` in the query string in the bottom-most link in the HTTPFox history to obtain the `redirect_uri`.

You have to literally make sure the Return URL is the exact same sequence of characters as the input `redirect_uri`.  For example, if one points to "localhost" and the other to "127.0.0.1", it won't recognize the `redirect_uri` value as the same. It also won't recognize `redirect_uri` if only one of the `redirect_uri` values has a final slash.

Yes, the return URL was able to be updated in my experience.